# How to write a txt file from spark scala Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, txt

I want to write a Dataframe as a .txt file along with headers and delimited with | and text separator as ".I know we can create it as .CSV file but I do not want the extension to be .CSV

**sample txt file below**

```
"RollNum"|"Name"|"subject"|"Marks"
"12345"|"aaa"|"science"|"50"
"12345"|"aaa"|"social"|"45"
"12345"|"aaa"|"maths"|"89"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text`, but text can accept only one column ( so basically you need to convert all the columns as a single column before you write)

```
df.write.text("testpath")
```